# Colocar valor no Paragrafo sem que o javascript interprete Tag HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html-tags

Tenho um paragrafo`<p id='meuParagrafo' >paragra</p>`
e no JavaScript quero fazer isso `document.querySelector("#meuParagrafo").innerHTML = "<b>Bem legal</b>";` o único problema é que a tag `<b>` deixatia meu código em negrito, e eu não quero isso, eu quero que o paragrafo aparece a tag `<b>Bem legal</b>` sem o negrito

OBS: Estou fazendo um chat, por isso não posso deixar a interpretação das Tags

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma procurada na internet, achei isso que resolveu meu problema

`SUA_STRING.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');`